# Equivalent of Rails console for Go

Tags: go

I am relatively new to Go and I was curious if there is a console that I can test go commands in. I essentially want a sandboxed environment that resets every time the console is opened. For those that know Rails, a experience similar to Rails console is desired.

Comment: [go-eval](https://github.com/sbinet/go-eval) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy Thanks, I think this is as close as I am going to get to the desired functionality. I was hoping to be able to test imported packages from a console like environment but I don't believe there is a solution to that at the current moment.

Comment: Just for future reference, the keyword you're looking for is "REPL," which is an acronym for "read-eval-print loop." Ruby's irb and the Rails console are examples of REPLs. There are a number of results for "golang repl" on Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+repl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Rails console, but the Go Playground (http://play.golang.org) provides a sandboxed environment to test Go code in. But it needs to be a complete Go program, not just typed in a line at a time like the console for an interpreted language like Ruby.